# Unable to mount samba share on old NAS device on Ubuntu 22.04 - kernel 5.15. Works on kernel 5.13

Tags: kernel, mount, samba, fstab

I think the title is pretty self-explanatory. But I will attempt to shed a little more light on my problem.
After upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04 and rebooting I noticed that a samba share I have on an old DNS-313 was unavailable. The fstab line I had with the **vers=1.0** parameter no longer worked and neither did a manual mount. After spending a fair amount of time trying to figure out what the problem was, whether it was a faulty disk or enclosure, I suspected that maybe the upgrade to a newer kernel might be the cause and lo and behold, it was. Since reverting to kernel 5.13, everything is working as intended.
Is my problem well-known and is there a fix or workaround so that I can use a newer and thus more secure kernel?
TIA for your time.
Cheers

Comment: Along with "vers=1.0" are you also passing "sec=ntlm"? If you are that's a problem since kernel 5.15 removed the ntlm sec option. Try a manual mount without it. Not sure what to do if the NAS actually requires that option.

Comment: Well, no, that option is not set. But I have read some forums since and it seems I'm out of luck as support for older insecure samba versions seemed to have been dropped in recent kernels apparently starting with 5.15. It's bad that such a decision was not mitigated by a possibility to set an option in fstab so that users can still use perfectly fine hardware even if legacy, especially as I use it only on my lan with no outside access. But I will wait to see if people in my situation (and more savvy than me) can come up with a solution while still using recent kernels.